# What will happen to contacts which are in middle of a Journey and we update the Journey in Journey Builder?

Tags: journeybuilder, send-email, marketing-cloud

Let's say we have 6 steps (all send email) in Journey builder. There are contacts who are already on Step 4, 5 and now we update email templates for all 6 steps and add new data. What will happen to the existing contacts in terms of receiving email templates?
Logically all existing and new contacts should be receiving new emails but wanted to confirm and also want to know how does Marketing cloud tracks this if email have been sent already to a contact for a particular step or not?

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer is partially correct; updates to emails don't automatically get published as these are Triggered Send Emails.

However, I would not recommend stopping the Interaction as this will eject all Contacts from the Interaction.

You can pause the Triggered Send from the Email App and then click Publish Changes, but you can also easily update the email **directly from within a running Interaction** without creating a new version:

1. Hover over the Email Activity in the running Interaction and click 'Select More Details'
2. In the Send Email modal, click Next
3. Click Done
4. Close the modal by selecting the X icon in the top right corner

That's it. Your email will be republished. You can validate this by opening Triggered Emails from the Interactions menu in the Email app, then under Journey Builder Sends in the left panel, select the corresponding Interaction name and version — you will note that the Published date for the Email has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

It wont get auto published.

Basically Journey Builder is a combination of triggered sends. In case you define a template and use it in the journey.

Go back to the journey and make some changes. 
These changes wont be reflected to subscribers, you need to manually stop the journey reselect the email.

In this way the email gets re published.

Thanks

Comment: True, but you can also go into the 'Triggered Emails' section of Email Studio and manually pause and re-publish the triggers. This would update the emails used in the Journey. Just be careful when pausing triggers used in live Journeys!

Answer (score 0):

I usually go into the journey, select the step which has changed, and click 'view or update activity' then just click 'Next' twice to reselect your email template (unless you want to switch it for another one, in which case choose it), and publish it.

At the end it says something like 'Changes to your template have been published'. So if you want to just update to a new template or publish changes you made to the existing one you can do this without stopping your journey, but if you need to fundamentally alter the paths of your journey, you have to stop it and eject your contacts.