# What happens to contacts that are in a journey when a new version is updated with new activities?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a current journey that needs to be updated with new interactions. If I add these new interactions (Email, SMS etc), will the contacts already in the journey be kicked out and admitted to the new version?

I saw this answer, but it doesn't fully answer my questions:

[What will happen to contacts which are in middle of a Journey and we update the Journey in Journey Builder?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133400/what-will-happen-to-contacts-which-are-in-middle-of-a-journey-and-we-update-the)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Contacts that are moving through a running Journey version will continue to move through that same version when a new version is published.

Contacts in previous versions are not migrated across to the new version.

When you publish a new version, any new Contacts that are injected into the Journey will enter the new published version.